# Weird Attribute in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

When I tried to inspect one of the textbox in IE8, I found that there is weird attribute in the tag. This does not happened in only checkbox and textbox, all input type include `select` as well.

Where is this attribute came from? If it is valid, what does it mean?

```
jQuery17204372428416893459="14"

<INPUT onblur="" id="id1" class="class1" onkeyup="" onclick="" onchange="" maxLength="30" size="200" name="name1" autocomplete="off" jQuery17204372428416893459="14" value="" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [strange jquery attribute added on checkbox in ie8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19783097/strange-jquery-attribute-added-on-checkbox-in-ie8)

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that you are seeing the same issue with this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/B4TyL/1/

> This "expando" attribute is used by jQuery to keep track of the events
>   bound to your checkbox element. If you can't check it, that's probably
>   because you have an event handler function preventing it.

**Try this:**

You'll need to modify your jquery source. For example, 1.6.2:
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js

Includes the following:

```
jQuery.extend({
    cache: {},

    // Please use with caution
    uuid: 0,

    // Unique for each copy of jQuery on the page
    // Non-digits removed to match rinlinejQuery
    expando: "jQuery" + ( jQuery.fn.jquery + Math.random() ).replace( /\D/g, "" ),
```

You can change the expando line as follows:

```
    // Does not support multiple copies of jQuery on the same page!
    // 0 included to match rinlinejQuery (/jQuery\d+/)
    expando: "jQuery0",
```

Comment: Does it only can be seen in IE8? Because I tested on Chrome and Mozilla, but it doesn't have this attribute.

Comment: Yes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3529339/3412545 , which Chrome / Mozilla version are you using?

Comment: Chrome `43.0.2357.124` and Mozilla `38.0.5`. So basically, I can just ignore the jQuery event attribute that seen in IE8?

Comment: Yes, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2760928/3412545. "The numeric value assigned to the expando is an incrementing counter that references its location in the jQuery cache object."