# What is the relevance of clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000

Tags: javascript, jquery

From the jQuery 1.7rc1 source:

```
noData: {
    "embed": true,
    // Ban all objects except for Flash (which handle expandos)
    "object": "clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000",
    "applet": true
},
```

What is `clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000`?

Comment: Google is a great tool for finding what a guid is: http://www.google.com/search?q=D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000

Comment: I've made the search, but I don't understand the results.

Comment: If you read the comment in the code and the first result from Google, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: This is now the first result listed. We've come full circle!

Comment: [`{D27CDB6E-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000}`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737898%28WS.10%29.aspx), Microsoft’s GUID for representing _Shockwave Flash_, which you might be able to find in a museum at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever an object is not a [Shockwave flash](http://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/cc737898%28WS.10%29.aspx) object, setting expando properties won't work (["expando property"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506005/javascript-expando-objects)), as uncatchable errors will be thrown. From a glance at the source, this method is interna

From the source:

```
// The following elements throw uncatchable exceptions if you
// attempt to add expando properties to them.
noData: {
    "embed": true,
    // Ban all objects except for Flash (which handle expandos)
    "object": "clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000",
    "applet": true
},
```

Search in [the source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7rc1.js) for `noData`, and many references with appropriate comments appear.

Answer (score 1):

According to the code, the point is to

> Ban all objects except for Flash (which handle expandos)

This means that the line `"object": "clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"` is used to blacklist Flash objects.  The [first result from Google](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737898%28WS.10%29.aspx) states that the GUID stores "configuration data for the policy setting Shockwave Flash".