# Adding properties dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript

In Javascript you add properties to an object dynamically for example:

```
var car = {colour: "blue"};
car.reg = "XYXABC00D";
```

Is there a special buzzword for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you just looking for a single word that means "dynamically adding a property to an object"?

Comment: @Pter yes, the question is that simple

Answer (score 2):

Your buzzword might be called the **expando**.

- [Javascript expando objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506005/javascript-expando-objects)

> Well, in javascript, any object is an expando object. What it means
>   is, as the article covers, that whenever you try to access a property
>   it will automatically be created.

In practice the name "expando" is only used when a dynamic property added to a DOM node, which made "funny" things in ancient Internet Explorer versions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "In practice it is only used when a dynamic property is added to a DOM node". I dynamically add keys to objects quite frequently...

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the expression "expando" is generally used in DOM context, especially when IE memory leaks are discussed.

Comment: What's the word to cover the programming technique when there is no DOM?

Comment: What's wrong with "I added a `date` property to object `o`"? :)

Answer (score 0):

Since objects in javascript are associative arrays, adding a dynamic property is simply mapping a key/value pair.  So perhaps the technical term you're looking for is probably related to assigning/mapping (terms that are related to associative arrays instead of the dynamic object).