# Split JSON object with square backet names into sub objects

Tags: javascript, json, forms

We're serializing a form using `serializeObject` and then storing this into local storage as a JSON encoded string. When we decode this back out of LocalStorage, we have keys with the name of `flight[inbound][0][iso]` and `flight[outbound][1][date]` etc. This makes it difficult to properly loop through later on (in JavaScript) as we need to now repopulate the form with the stored data.

Is there a way of further decoding these key names into sub-objects? For example:

```
flight[outbound][0][datetime] = "Something";
flight[outbound][0][from]     = "Something";
flight[outbound][0][to]       = "Something";
flight[outbound][0][carrier]  = "Something";
flight[inbound][0][datetime]  = "Something";
flight[inbound][0][from]      = "Something";
flight[inbound][0][to]        = "Something";
flight[inbound][0][carrier]   = "Something";
```

Should turn into:

```
flight = {
    outbound: {
        0: {
            datetime: "Something",
            from:     "Something",
            to:       "Something",
            carrier:  "Something",
        }
    },
    inbound: {
        0: {
            datetime: "Something else",
            from:     "Something else",
            to:       "Something else",
            carrier:  "Something else",
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the code of `serializeObject` ? This should be wrong on the step of serializing to the right object.

Comment: I lied. It's https://gist.github.com/jbrooksuk/11248775

Comment: What does the JSON look like? If your turning JSON into a JS object you should use [JSON.Parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: @James So it's a jQuery plugin? Any way, could you create a jsfiddle to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Also see [Javascript expando objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506005/javascript-expando-objects) `flight[outbound]` is directly equal to `flight.outbound` or `flight={outbound:{...}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `serializeObject` plugin we're using wasn't doing the right job. Switching it for https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object has provided us with what we're after.

Comment: You know this is build into JavaScript now don't you? You don't need a plugin at all. Also the default polyfill Json serializer is [http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/](http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/). This is the one built on JSON2 which was written by the guy who invented JSON.